# Asynchronous Add/Update save method not updating

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am building a .NET page for a project that adds a new City and State for a new user or updates the City and state if their ID is already in the database. Everything is working fine except for the fact that if a past user clicks submit to update their information, an entirely new entry is added to the database.

I have created the method already in the repository listed below.

```
public async Task<LocationViewModel> SaveLocationAsync(LocationViewModel model)
    {

        try
        {
            var location = new Location()
            {

                City = model.City,
                State = model.State

            };
            if (model.Id != 0)
            {
                location.Id = model.Id;
            }
            _dbcontext.Location.AddOrUpdate(location);
            await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return model;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.Error = true;
            model.ErrorMessages = new List<string>()
            {
                string.Format("Something went wrong - Message: {0} \n Stack Trace: {1}", ex.Message,
                    ex.StackTrace)
            };
            return model;
        }
    }
```

I have also  built a controller that saves and updates existing records asynchronously shown below.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public async Task<LocationViewModel> SaveLocationApiAsync(LocationViewModel model)
        {
            var result = new LocationViewModel();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                result = await _locationRepository.SaveLocationAsync(model);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

In addition, I have added added all of my routes and references.

Why is a new entry put in the database instead of the current one updating? The Javascript is shown below.

```
self.Submit = function () {
            if (self.errors().length !== 0) {
                self.errors.showAllMessages();
                return;
            }
            if (isNumber(locationId)) {
                self.Location().LocationId(locationId);
                swal("Success", "Thank you for your submission \nYour information has been updated.", "success");

            }

            var newData = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.Location());
            var url = "/Admin/SaveLocationApiAsync/Post/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: newData,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Error === true) {
                        swal("Error", result.ErrorMessages.join('\n'), "error");
                    } else {
                        //TOdo
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    swal("Error", "Something went wrong.\nPlease contact help.", "error");
                }
            });
        };
```

I apologize if it is a lot. I have checked everything repeatedly and have fixed all bugs. I am out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your url looks to the controller action seems incorrect. You have `var url = "/Admin/SaveLocationApiAsync/Post/";` when it should be `var url = "/Admin/SaveLocationApiAsync";`

Another approach to getting the correct url would be:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("SaveLocationApiAsync", "<ControllerName>")';
```

Also, in your ajax error handler you can get the HTTP status code and error message, which would help.

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    swal("Error", "Something went wrong.\nPlease contact help.", "error");
                }
```

**EDIT:**

I should have prefaced that using Url.Action works when your JavaScript is in a view (assuming Razor view in this case).

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is great tool to use when debugging ajax calls.